# NameError: name 'fish' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python and trying to figure out the problem i'm facing.  I'm getting following error msg:

```
     16     return output
     17 
---> 18 print(fishstore(fish, price))
     19 
     20 

NameError: name 'fish' is not defined
```

Script i'm working on:

```
def fishname():
    user_input=input("Enter Name: ")
    return (user_input.title())

def number():
    number_input=input("Enter Price: ")
    return number_input

def fishstore(fish, price):     
    fish_entry = fishname()     
    price_entry = number()    
    output = "Fish Type: " + fish_entry + ", costs $" + price_entry
    return output

print(fishstore(fish, price))
```

Could someone explain what i'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

Thank you all for help.  so i did some work and made change...

```
def fishstore(fish, price):     
    output = "Fish Type: " + fish + ", costs $" + price
    return output

fish_entry = input("Enter Name: ")
fish = fish_entry
price_entry = input("Enter Price: ")
price = price_entry

print(fishstore(fish, price))
```

and it worked.  Thank you all for help!

Comment: Think about it. Where do you define the values of `fish` and `price`?

Comment: Well, you *don't* define `fish` or `price`, so what's the question?

Comment: Thank you all!  I think I misread the practice question I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're defining the method you're naming arguments:

```
def fishstore(fish, price):
```

When you're calling the method you're referencing two variables that don't exist:

```
fishstore(fish, price)
```

You probably mean:

```
fishstore(fishname(), number())
```

The result of `fishname()` ends up being `fish` within the context of that `fishstore` method, likewise with `number()` becoming `price`. Outside of that specific context those variables don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because variable names fish and price are not defined in your program.

```
print(fishstore(fish, price))
```

I think you are trying to read the values from user and passing it to fishstore()

This will help you.

## version 1

Read inputs directly from fishstore() function.

```
def fishname():
    user_input=input("Enter Name: ")
    return (user_input.title())

def number():
    number_input=input("Enter Price: ")
    return number_input

def fishstore():     
    fish_entry = fishname()     
    price_entry = number()    
    output = "Fish Type: " + fish_entry + ", costs $" + price_entry
    return output

print(fishstore())
```

## version 2

```
def fishname():
    user_input=input("Enter Name: ")
    return (user_input.title())

def number():
    number_input=input("Enter Price: ")
    return number_input

def fishstore(fish_entry, price_entry):        
    output = "Fish Type: " + fish_entry + ", costs $" + price_entry
    return output 

print(fishstore(fishname(), number()))
```

Both versions will give you the result you are expecting.

```
output:
Enter Name: tilapia
Enter Price: 10
Fish Type: Tilapia, costs $10
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!